# For Slack API, What's the different between scopes in settings under "OAuth & Permissions" tab and scopes when request an access token

Tags: slack-api

For Slack API, What's the different between scopes in settings under "OAuth & Permissions" tab and scopes when request an access token (https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2#overview)? Do they have to be the same? What happens if I request more scopes when requesting an access token and what happens if I request less?

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that the requested scopes (during OAuth grant flow) should be less than or equal to the scopes in the settings. :)

Comment: Is there any reason to repeat this? Maybe for security?

Comment: Could be, sometimes you want to request scopes for the app only when necessary. e.g. you'd request access to public profile when logging in and then you would request access to channel messages to enable some kinda notification.